# checkbox in div of position fixed not clickable (ie8/compatibility mode)

Tags: checkbox, ie8-compatibility-mode, css-position

Here is something that's driving me mad for a while:

Browser: **IE8/Compatibility Mode**

Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Html:

```
<div style="position:fixed;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="what" name="what" />
</div>
```

The above checkbox **does not react to clicking**.

Anyone knows what can be done?

Thanks!!!